# UnicodeDecodeError in converting shapefile into GeoJSON file

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, geojson, shapefile

I've tried to convert 'shapefile' into 'geojson' format using python and this is my code

```
import shapefile
import json

path = "shapefiles/WTL_VALV_PS"
sf = shapefile.Reader(path)

fields = sf.fields[1:]
field_names = [field[0] for field in fields]

buffer = []
for sr in sf.shapeRecords():
    atr = dict(zip(field_names, sr.record))

    geom = sr.shape.__geo_interface__
    buffer.append(dict(type="Feature", geometry=geom, properties=atr))

    geojson = open("test4.geojson", "w", encoding='utf-8')
    geojson.write(json.dumps({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": buffer}, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
    geojson.close()
```

but I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ConvertGeoJSON/geoJSON.py", line 16, in <module>
    for sr in sf.shapeRecords():
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ConvertGeoJSON\venv\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 1039, in shapeRecords
    for rec in zip(self.shapes(), self.records())])
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ConvertGeoJSON\venv\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 1012, in records
    r = self.__record(oid=i)
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ConvertGeoJSON\venv\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 987, in __record
    value = u(value, self.encoding, self.encodingErrors)
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ConvertGeoJSON\venv\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 104, in u
    return v.decode(encoding, encodingErrors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I thought it is becuase shapefile contains 'Korean character' but I could convert file with Arabic character like 'أفغانستان ' and of course I could convert file with English.

I lost my way and I don't know where I'm supposed to start from

Comment: Apparently this shapefile isn't encoded with UTF-8. You need to check the source from where you got the file; maybe it tells you what text encoding was used or if maybe there is compression involved. Then you can probably pass this information to `shapefile.Reader()` (I'm not sure about the last part; couldn't find the `shapefile` package).

Comment: @lenz I found the .dbf file in shapefiles is encoded with EUC-KR. So I converted it into UTF-8 format with LibreOffice then it worked well. Thanks for your comment!!